# Splitting strings without creating a new table or string_split()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have strings that have really only one rule: There will always be a delimiter of '/' with a frequency of 2.

Examples:

```
1/2/3

111/222222/3

asdf/dd/eds
```

How can I do this without string_split() or making a new table to split this string into 3?

I've made several attempts, but there is always something slightly incorrect.

Assume for the example below that 'str' is one of the samples mentioned above.

```
select
    substring(str,0,charindex('/',str,0)) as first, 
    substring(str,charindex('/',str,0) + 1,charindex('/',strcharindex('/',strcharindex('/',str,0) + 1))) as 2nd,
    --3rd
```

Comment: Why only with those 3 functions?

Comment: I updated my description to further clarify what I don't want instead of limiting to certain functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your requirements, but no need for `LEN()`

```
declare @var varchar(64) = '111/222222/3'

select 
    substring(@var,1,charindex('/',@var) - 1)
    ,substring(@var,charindex('/',@var) + 1,charindex('/',substring(@var,charindex('/',@var) + 1,99)) - 1)
    ,substring(substring(@var,charindex('/',@var) + 1,99),charindex('/',substring(@var,charindex('/',@var) + 1,99)) + 1,99)
```

Everywhere you see 99 change that to the max length of your string, or 8000 as a catch all

Comment: You are using`LEFT/RIGHT/REVERSE` functions here.

Comment: Still the reverse

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution in this case would be to (ab)use [`parsename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - using [`cross apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-apply) and [`replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT PARSENAME(val, 3) As col1,
       PARSENAME(val, 2) As col2,
       PARSENAME(val, 1) As col3
FROM Table
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT REPLACE(str, '/', '.') As val
) x
```

Following Martin Smith's comment - 
This will only work if the strings between the delimiters are no longer than 128 chars, and if the don't contain dots (though that's probably fixable with more replace statements, but that's going to make the entire thing more cumbersome)

Comment: This does add two implicit assumptions. The strings can't contain dots and each segment isn't longer than 128 chars

Comment: @MartinSmith Correct - Didn't think about that. Will edit that in.

Answer (score 2):

I find this easiest using `apply`:

```
select v1.first, v2.second, v2.third
from (values ('a/b/c')) t(str) cross apply
     (values (left(t.str, charindex('/', t.str) - 1),
              stuff(t.str, 1, charindex('/', t.str), '')
             )
     ) v1(first, rest) cross apply
     (values (left(v1.rest, charindex('/', v1.rest) - 1),
              stuff(v1.rest, 1, charindex('/', v1.rest), '')
             )
     ) v2(second, third);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e13d27aced54cd1fba05c56d39c7051e) is a db<>fiddle.

You can think of `stuff()` and `left()` as shorthands for `substring()`.

There are other alternatives, such as a `split()` function.  Unfortunately, the built-in split function doesn't provide an index for the resulting string.  So you can get the pieces but not in order.

You can also devise solutions using recursive CTEs and XML.  I simply prefer this method for such a specific problem.

Comment: _Splitting strings **with only** substring, charindex, and len()_

Comment: @Sami - The question doesn't specify **only** and even if it did it should likely be ignored. It is not as if there is a version of SQL Server that supports those but not `STUFF` for example

Comment: It's the OP requirements, not me.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand recently gave me a link showing a [nice little trick to get the correct order of substrings using the built in string split method](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5275/solve-old-problems-with-sql-servers-new-stringagg-and-stringsplit-functions/) (but it only works if the substrings are unique).

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('1/2/3')
,('111/222222/3')
,('asdf/dd/eds')


Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeCol,'/','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as B1
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol       Pos1  Pos2    Pos3
1/2/3         1     2       3
111/222222/3  111   222222  3
asdf/dd/eds   asdf  dd      eds
```