# split a column in two and sort in mssql

Tags: sql-server, select

I'm new to sql and i need to do this
in MSSQL:
I have a simple tble with userid, fullname,age and so on
where fullname is obviously firstname lastname like 'Adam Smith'

I need to sort the table according to surname only. Is there anyway?

Comment: what happens if you have a name like "Gabriel José de la Concordia García Márquez"?

Comment: they only have two parts

Comment: Do they always have two parts? You wouldn't have a name like "Madona" in there by any chance?

Comment: yes always two parts, not one, not three or more ;)

Comment: The best fix would be to have two columns, firstname and lastname. Or you could save them as lastname firstname, then you can order by fullname.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only 1 lastname then you could use the [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) trick.

It's a function that's normally used to get a specified part from an object name.
For example to get `'[mytable]'` from `'[myschema].[mydatabase].[mytable]'`.
So it splits the string by the dot.

Your string has spaces.
When the spaces  are replaced by dot, then it's easy to get the first element from the right via PARSENAME.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY parsename(replace(fullname,' ','.'),1)
```

But do note that PARSENAME returns NULL when there's more than 4 elements.

Comment: Check out [Martin Smith's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125802/splitting-strings-without-creating-a-new-table-or-string-split/53125949#comment93146693_53125949) on one of my answers suggesting this trick: (This does add two implicit assumptions. The strings can't contain dots and each segment isn't longer than 128 chars.) Might not be a problem in this case but it's a good thing to keep in mind.

Comment: @ZoharPeled True. Didn't know about that 128 chars rule. But indeed, this solution depends on some assumptions.

Comment: When you think about it, since `sysname` is, in fact, `nvarchar(128)`, it makes perfect sense.I don't think I knew about that rule before Martin pointed that out, though.

Comment: Heh, this does make me wonder if there are actually names out there that contains dots, or underscores. If you don't count the titles like 'Dr.' anyway.

Comment: I would guess there are such names. I mean, when you think about the artist formerly known as prince, you realize that names actually don't have any rules...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `right` with `charindex` and `reverse` to get the part of the string after the last space, like this:

First, create and populate sample table(**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    FullName nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T(FullName) VALUES
(N'Zohar Peled'),
(N'Amir Shahbabaie'),
(N'Madona'),
(N'Gabriel José de la Concordia García Márquez')
```

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T
ORDER BY RIGHT(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(FullName)))
```

Results:

```
FullName
Madona
Gabriel José de la Concordia García Márquez
Zohar Peled
Amir Shahbabaie
```

As you can see, this will also work if your strings are not what you expect (and when dealing with names, they rarely are what you expect)